# ответ Обновление события в Zabbix 5.4

Tags: zabbix

Имеется **Zabbix 5.4**.

В экране `Мониторинг`->`Панель` есть окно "`Последние 20 событий`".
В этом окне отображаются результаты работы триггеров.

**Например событие Oracle:**

```
no space on tablespace -SYSTEM use 85%.
```

После срабатывания триггера значение 85% в реальности может изменится на худшее значение - 90%. Но показываться все равно будет 85%.

**Как заставить zabbix обновлять значение?**

Я задавал такой же вопрос по версии 3.2.
И там работал макрос `{ITEM.LASTVALUE}`. 
Начиная с 4ой версии это так уже не работает.

**Есть варианты?**